# Differences in the rs232 series

Tags: usb, uart, rs232, ttl, esp8266

Another question on chips.  I want to program my esp8266 chip, and I need to know what to use.  I've ordered a rs232rl 3.3/5v selectable board, but I want to know if this will work with an arduino, picaxe, or any similar thing.  What's the difference between the rs232, the rs232r, and the rs232rl?  Thanks!

Comment: There is some problem with the switchable boards from some suppliers- the 3.3/5V  switch does  not do what  one would expect, and that's important for an ESP8266. Should be less of an issue with Sparkfun compared to random Asian suppliers on eB**or Al****.

Comment: I will make note of that, thanks!  Anyway, can you answer how the chips themselves are any different?

Comment: The datasheets are publicly available. Why don't you compare them yourself and ask questions if something appears confusing?

Comment: Obviously they are publicly available, but it's very hard for me to understand half of the things in there and determine the relevant information in it.

Comment: There is no such thing as "an rs232rl". Are you thinking of the FTDI FT232RL?

Comment: I have no idea @duskwuff I just saw the chip name listed as that so maybe u r right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've ordered a rs232rl 3.3/5v selectable board

You have, in all probability, made a mistake.

There is no such thing as "a RS232RL". This name is a mishmash of "RS232" -- [a serial signalling standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) which is probably not actually supported by this board -- and "FT232RL" -- the name of [a USB-to-serial chip produced by FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm).

There is a significant chance that the part on the board you receive will not be a genuine FTDI part. [Counterfeit FT232RL chips are quite common](http://zeptobars.com/en/read/FTDI-FT232RL-real-vs-fake-supereal), especially on inexpensive eBay/Alibaba hardware. The seller's use of an improper name for the part gives me very little confidence in their product.

For what it's worth, the names "FT232", "FT232R", and "FT232RL" are all closely related, and will typically all refer to the same part:

- FT232RL is the part name for the FT232 in the SSOP28 package. The FT232 is also available in QFN32 (as FT232RQ), but the SSOP28 package is far more common. (And is the package typically used by counterfeiters…)
- The FT232R is the most commonly used part in the FT232 family. The only other parts with similar names are the FT232H and FT232B; the former is significantly more expensive, and the latter has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: Thanks man.  I appreciate your answer.   As long as this counterfeit works, it's fine for me.  So the different models all use the same communication protocol, right?

Comment: The problem is that the counterfeits often **don't** work, especially with certain versions of Windows FTDI drivers.

Comment: It says, in all its bad english: Support 3.3V, 5V
Chipset FT232RL
USB power has over current protection, using 500MA self-restore fuse.  I hope this one works lol

Comment: How FTDI disabled fake chips and what you can do... https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/2k0i7x/watch_that_windows_update_ftdi_drivers_are/clgviyl/